# Uninstall MySQL

Tags: macos, mysql, mamp

I'm trying to get a working copy of MAMP. But I once installed the MySQL server seperately, and I can't find a way to uninstall.

[image] [image]

How can I uninstall this version of MySQL?

Comment: Have a look at this answer on superuser:

http://superuser.com/questions/129193/how-do-i-uninstall-mysql-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/129193/how-do-i-uninstall-mysql-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard) and [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436425/how-do-you-uninstall-mysql-from-mac-os-x) both say approximately the same thing, that you need to perform the following actions:

> If you haven't yet rebooted your computer, the process could still be
>   running. First, reboot.
>
> Then if MySQL is still showing up after a reboot, from the Terminal,
>   issue the following commands one at a time:
>
> - `sudo rm /usr/local/mysql`
> - `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*`
> - `sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM`
> - `sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*`
> - `rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*`
> - `sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*`
> - `sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*`
>
> And using your text editor of choice:
>
> - Edit `/etc/hostconfig` and remove the line `MYSQLCOM=-YES-`
>
> If you still cannot install or run a different version of MySQL, you might have to
>   issue [one last command in the Terminal](http://blog.egopoly.com/2009/09/01/how-to-uninstall-mysql-5-1-on-snow-leopard/):
>
> - `sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.mysql*`

Comment: OK, great. I was able to install a different version of MySQL. But the icon still appears in the system preferences, any thought why?

Comment: @Michiel So you've now got two MySQL icons in System Preferences? What happens if you right click on the old icon and select `Remove "MySQL" Preference Pane`?

Comment: Ok, this is cool :) I didn't know it was possible to manually delete the icon. I've got another MySQL installed and the icon doesn't show up in my System Preferences anymore. So, problem solved! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should check the following folders:

- /Applications
- /Developer
- /Library
- /System/Library
- /Users/your_user/Applications

It's bound to be in one of them!

Once you find the app, I suggest using [AppZapper](http://appzapper.com/) to completely remove it.

**Updated:** If you still can't find it open the terminal and run:

```
sudo find / -name "mysql
```

If there's *any* mysql executable in your computer it will find it

Comment: Thanks, but there is no MySQL file and or folder in either of these folders.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an additional step, try it out.